# BGP Inter-AS option A

Tags: cisco

[image]

How do I configure Inter AS option A for back-to-back VRF connectivity?

Can anyone please provide me with a sample configuration and topology for back to back VRFs ( Inter-AS option A )?

Basically, I am looking how to configure these two ASBRs (R3 and R4) with Inter-As option A in the above topology. The iBGP peering has already been done. The only thing I am left with to start is the eBGP peering.

Comment: Why do you want to do option A?

Comment: Yes. I want to configure inter as option a

Comment: But why option A?

Comment: Not exaclty, this is just for learning purpose. Are there any drawbacks with using option A ? Why shouldn't i use option A ?

Comment: I was trying to understand your requirements.   Generally, option A doesn't scale very well.  Do you have your two MPLS networks already set up?

Comment: @RonTrunk attached topology.

Comment: What is the connection between the two AS's?  Is it a trunk?  How many VRFs do you have?

Comment: No, it's not a trunk. These are just physical interfaces and for my simplicity I have only vrf configured on both the AS's.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial config, as I assume you already have BGP running on the PE routers, and the interfaces are in the correct vrf.  Each ASBR treats the other as a CE router:

```
router bgp 100
address-family ipv4 vrf AS-200
neighbor a.b.c.d remote-as 200
neighbor a.b.c.d activate
exit-address-family
```

Do the same for AS 200

Comment: This was the exact thing i was looking for. It worked. Thanks alot !!